# How to update rows from a recursive result?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, recursion, sql-update

I have a table that represents a simple directory structure (`set_id`, `parent_id -> set_id`). Now in my application when I update a directory I want all the parents in the tree to recursively update. I tried

```
with recursive parents as (
    select *
    from sets
    where set_id=$1

    union all

    select s.*
    from sets s
    join parents p on p.parent_id=s.set_id
)
update parents
set updated=now();
```

But I have an error that says the table children doesn't exist. I think I'm too tired I can't see another way around now, anyone can help ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join back the table in the `update`:

```
with recursive parents as (
    select * from sets where set_id=$1
    union all
    select s.* from sets s join parents p on p.parent_id=s.set_id
)
update sets s
set updated = now()
from parents p
where p.id = s.id;
```